# How to store the bit pattern of a 32 bit integer in a 32 length string of 0s and 1s in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I'm trying to figure out how to do what I described in the title. However there are some rules. I can only use bit-level operations to determine whether a character is 0 or 1. So no function calls, macro invocations, addition, subtraction, division, modulus, or multiplication.

I most likely will wind up using XOR and/or bit shifting. I'm just unsure exactly how to go about it. I found a question on here someone asked that's similar but it involves converting from a string to an int. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well, you will always have 32 characters, so you can create a `char buffer[33] = 0`, then as you iterate through the bits, your index should line up with the position in the buffer (or `32 - i`).  Test bits with a mask `bits & 1<<(32-i)`.  Use the ternary operator to write a `'1'` or `'0'` to the `buffer[i]`.

Comment: Nothing much. Mostly just research on bit level operations. That's how i discovered I would most likely be using XOR and bit shifting. And James, I'm really new to C. What is a ternary operator?

Comment: @Buster232 Select the text "ternary operator" in your browser, right-click, choose the option to search for it. If your browser is set to pass the search term to a search engine which remembers your previous searches, it will become attuned to presenting more relevant results for you.

Comment: What's with the rules?  Is this some kind of puzzle, or quiz?  At any rate, are you able to solve this problem at all (ignoring the artificial rules)?  (And if not, we're gonna have to focus on that first, and then maybe rewrite it again later, to comply with the rules.)

Comment: It's one thing to learn how to convert decimal to binary.  That's a super useful exercise.  It's quite another thing to do it with silly restrictions in place.  In my opinion it's not interesting, and teaches you nothing.  Yet for some reason your instructor wants you to do it.  If you do it, it teaches you nothing, and if we do it for you, it still teaches you nothing.  It's like someone asks you to build you a house, only you're not allowed to use wood, nails, screws, bricks, or cement; you're restricted to corn flakes, marbles, and bits of string.  Utterly pointless.

Comment: That's been my thought more than once. The same thing as when my professors freshman year asked me to to write a program to raise a number to a power in Java, but I wasn't allowed to use Math.pow(). Took me forever to figure out how to do it the dumb way. Oh, and my current prof gave our class this assignment before we'd even learned C. I'm having to learn C, and Linux, and vim, and the project itself all at once.

Answer (score 3):

```
char *uintToChar(uint32_t uint, char *buff)
{
    char *wptr = buff;

    for(uint32_t i = 1ul << 31; i ; i >>= 1)
    {
        *wptr++ = (uint & i) ? '1' : '0';
    }
    *wptr = 0;
    return buff;
}


int main(void)
{
    char d[33];

    printf("%s\n", uintToChar(0xf0f0f0f0, d));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. My function for this is void. Does that mean that I should take out the last two lines of *uintToChar()?

Comment: I can increment in the loop. I just can't use +, -, *, /, %, etc.

Comment: @chqrlie yes - reused for from another code - but does not change anything except the satisfaction of the nitpick.

Comment: So what should I do with the last two statements in the function? My function is void so I can't return anything

Comment: last one only the *wptr = 0 is needed

Comment: @Buster232: just remove the `return buff;` statement.

Comment: and change the printf

Comment: for my code it gave me an error saying that uint32_t was an undefined type. I changed it to int but that isn't working either. Also can someone explain what wptr means?